# Javascript - split string dynamically

Tags: javascript, string, split

I am trying to use javascript or angularjs to make a table header titles return the words in parentheses on their own line. Therefore for instance

```
abcdefg (x yz)
```

, should make the title look like this:

```
abcdefg 
(x yz)
```

I tried to split on parentheses but this returns every word separated and then i would need to reconstruct the string into 2 parts.

Comment: If always in the given format, you should split on the first space.

Comment: You mean `"abdefg (x yz)".split('(').join('<br />(')`? Although that might create problems with more than 1 `(` sign

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272773/split-string-on-the-first-white-space-occurrence

Comment: @Icepickle so thanks for the answer. however it returns this 
`abc </br >(x yz)`

Comment: Well, angular doesn't allow for html to be inserted freely

Answer (score 0):

This is doing the job:

```js
var test = [
    "abcdefg x yz",
    "abcdefg (x yz)",
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a.replace(/(?=\()/, '<br>');
}));
```

Where `(?=\()` is a positive lookahead, a zero-length assertion that makes sure we have an open parenthesis. The replacement is made just before this parenthesis.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this is what I get though as result on the screen: abc </br >(x yz)